# How to get first two word from a string value

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-layout

I have two String: "I am a Beginner", "Hello Dear App Developer"
How can I get only the first two words using Java "I am" "Hello Dear"

```
String TextOne = "I am a Beginner"
String TextTwo = "Hello Dear App Developer"
I need only "I am" and "Hello Dear"
```

Comment: `String s1 = "I am"; String s2 = "Hello Dear"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split string by space(" ")

```
String TextOne = "I am a Beginner";
String[] strList = TextOne.split(" "); //["I", "am", "a", "Beginner"]
String finalTextOne = strList[0] + " " + strList[1];  
Log.e("finalTextOne: ", finalTextOne); // It will print "I am"
```

Comment: Thank You So much it is working fine